# Elegant way of assigning value to variable according to the value of another variable

Tags: python

I need to assign the value of a variable `b` according to where another variable, `a`, is positioned in a range of values.

This is what I currently do:

```
if a > 2.:
    b = 10
elif 1. < a <= 2.:
    b = 15
elif 0.5 < a <= 1.:
    b = 20
elif 0.2 < a <= 0.5:
    b = 25
elif a <= 0.2:
    b = 30
```

This works, but it isn't pretty. Is there a more elegant/pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: `bounds = { (float('inf'), 2.): 10, (1., 2.): 15, ... etc}` -- if it's between the bounds, return the value.

Comment: I don't see much wrong with your own approach, at least it is readable

Comment: What is the nature of the relationship of `b` and `a`? Can you just calculate `b` from `a` and round to the nearest 5?

Comment: @BrianCain could you make an answer out of the cmmt?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know, it works and it is readable, but I'd like something more succinct which (to me) looks better.

Comment: @aganders3 not really, I have no clear relation between these two variables beyond what the `if` block shows.

Comment: I agree with Padraic.  Besides, the current approach is also very efficient.  Anything else will reduce performance since it will require function calls, building data structures, etc.

Comment: Your `<=` checks are superfluous since the previous check will ensure that it is already true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `bisect` function with a pair of lists.

```
import bisect
a_values = [0, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
b_values = [30, 25, 20, 15, 10]
b = b_values[bisect.bisect_left(a_values, a)-1]
```

Comment: `0.2` should be 30 not 25

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're right, it should have been bisect_left, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following for calculating `b`:

```
for x, b in zip([2., 1., 0.5, 0.2, 0.0], range(10, 35, 5)):
    if a > x:
        break
```

Or if you prefer:

```
b = 10 + 5 * next(i for i, v in enumerate([2., 1., 0.5, 0.2, 0.0]) if a > v)
```

Or:

```
b = 5 * next(i for i, v in enumerate([2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0], 2) if a > v)
```

Comment: Your second function looks much better although perhaps using a function for this would be a bit overkill. +1

Comment: Ok you convinced me...but why anyone hates functions? :p

Comment: Oh this peer pressure...I hope you approve now...oops I have a break :)

Comment: That is actually a very good answer. Now you've made me doubt which one I should accept...

Answer (score 0):

save your `b` values and their lower boundary into a

```
dic = {0.2: 30, 0.5: 25, 0.5: 20, 1: 20, 2: 10}
```

filter your dictionary's keys by being larger/equal than your number under test and find the minimum:

```
keys_sufficient = filter(lamba k: k <= a, dic.keys())
b = dic[max(keys_sufficient)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the bounds as a `dict` and then search that.

```
def search(val_in):
    bounds = { (float('inf'), 2.): 10, (1., 2.): 15, ... (0.2, float('-inf')): 30}
    for (upper, lower), val_out in bounds.items():
        if (upper > val_in > lower):
            return val_out
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think you need a different way to do that. It's readable, understandable, and efficient. It takes up some space, sure, and it's somewhat of a pain to type, but I prefer code that takes up a bit of space over code that I have to look up to fully understand later on.

If you are working with a very large number of ranges, you might need something more compact to avoid tedium and inefficient time usage, but in this case I don't see a good reason to change anything.